# Ocorrência de letra na string - C

Tags: c, string, ponteiro

Boa tarde,

O meu objetivo é inserir uma string de até 500 caracteres, e então ler uma letra. Criando, para isso uma função que conte quantas vezes aquela letra aparece no texto.

O problema é que devo passar o texto por referência para a função e não sei se está funcionando.
A função deve receber o texto, a letra e retornar o número de repetições da letra.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int contagem(char *txt, char letra)
{
    int contagem=0;
    int i;

    for (i=0; txt[i] !='\0';i++)
    {
        if (txt[i]==letra)
            contagem++;
    }
return contagem;
}


int main()
{
char txt[501],letra;

printf("Insira o texto:");
scanf("%s", txt);

printf("Deseja contar ocorrencia de qual letra?");
scanf(" %c", letra);

printf("O caracter aparece %d vezes \n", contagem(*txt,letra));
}
```

Comment: Aqui: `scanf(" %c", letra);` faltou o `&`: `scanf(" %c", &letra);`. Aqui: `contagem(*txt,letra)` o correto é: `contagem(txt, letra)`.

Comment: Fiz essa correção, porém, após inserir a string e a letra que quero buscar, o prompt de comando congela e fecha.

Comment: Diferencie o nome da variável utilizada para contar do nome da função. Caso sua string possua caracteres espaço substitua `%s`por `[^\n]`, senão o programa encerrará a leitura no primeiro espaço. Veja funcionando em: https://ideone.com/Psm2UM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você vai passar um array por referência para uma função, em sua chamada você simplesmente coloca o nome do identificador do mesmo, no seu caso:

```
contagem(txt, letra);
```

Isso já deve resolver seu problema, porém fica uma dica: você visivelmente é novato, portanto obtenha o costume de testar seu código com amostras menores. Pegue um texto com 10 palavras e teste se seu programa está funcionando, é a melhor forma de responder o seu questionamento "não sei se está funcionando".

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Resolvido o problema, eu estou tentando aprender sozinho então estou encontrando algumas dificuldades mesmo.